# Understanding Python Syntax / Notation

Tags: python, syntax

Coming from a C++ background, I'm having a little bit of difficulty understanding Python in some situations.  For instance, in a GUI app using `Tkinter`, you might have:

```
button = Button (master, option=value, ...)
```

I know what the code is doing (creating a Button object), but I'm trying to figure out the exact details.  I'm guessing that `button` is becoming a pointer to a `Button` object, and `Button (master, option=value, ...)` is a call to the constructor, but its hard to see, since I am used to explicit data types and the `new` operator.  My guess could be entirely off though.

Comment: Have you tried working through the first few chapters of any python book, or worked through a python tutorial? Nothing in your question is tkinter-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I went through several guides and documents on this prior to this question, but just stumbled across the answer [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html):

"To create a pushbutton in a top-level window or frame named parent:

```
w = tk.Button(parent, option=value, ...)
```

The constructor returns the new Button widget."

So it seems to be just a normal object (non-pointer) and the constructor returns a `Button` object to it.

Comment: All names in Python are references (pointers) to objects, so your description in the question is more correct.

Comment: So there are no non-reference types in Python?

Comment: Some types are immutable, which makes them act as value types, but all names in Python are references to objects.  Extension modules can provide more efficient storage mechanisms (C or Fortran-style packed arrays of values in Numpy, for example), but the Python interpreter only deals with references.